# Exception raised during rendering: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.resolveSizeAndState(III)I

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm using android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

And imported the library v7 gridlayout, but get this error: Exception raised during rendering: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.resolveSizeAndState(III)I

In Android Private Libraries appear android-support-v4.jar

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the android-support-v4.jar file. Note that if you're using an external library such as ActionBarSherlock, you may need to update the jar in that library rather than in your own project.